# Sort mixed SOLR field by starting number (integer + string content)

Tags: string, solr, integer, numbers, field

I have SOLR running and configured a field like this:

```
<field name="XYZFieldname_s" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

My indexed SOLR documents look like this:

```
"docs": [
      {
        "XYZFieldname_s": "40000 abc"
      },
      {
        "XYZFieldname_s": "50 abc"
      },
      {
        "XYZFieldname_s": "50000 abc"
      },
      {
        "XYZFieldname_s": "no data"
      },
```

When i do `sort XYZFieldname_s asc`

I get

```
40000 abc
50 abc
50000 abc
no data
```

but i want to achive

```
5 abc
40000 abc
50000 abc
no data
```

how can i do this?
i looked up the doc https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_6/common-query-parameters.html but its not explained there. i assume for integer sorting i would ne a integer field but my field must contain the string as well.

looking forward for your assitance, thanks!

Comment: Split the value into to separate fields and sort by both (`sort=number_field asc, string_field asc`) - that way you'll get the proper sort order for the integer part as well as the string part.

Comment: is there no different solution? that way is very much effort and also its not sensitive since the data fields are mixed.. i can not split them clean into int/string...